# Variable table name in SQL Server + variable look-up

Tags: sql-server, variables

I have a query in which I'd like to make the table name `[TableX]` a variable.

This query needs to be executed several times with different variables. So I was wondering if is it possible to create a (temp) table in which the values of these variables could be looked up?

e.g.

```
list    language    Table
----------------------------
51      152         TableX
52      154         TableY
53      156         TableZ
```

Code:

```
declare @list int='51'       -- change
declare @language int='152'    -- change

insert into [DB].[Table] ([list], [value2], [language])
    Select 
        @list, value2, @language
    From
        [DB2].[TableX] -- change table name
```

Thank you

Comment: This is usually a sign of a broken data model - you're mixing data and metadata together in inappropriate ways. It's also usually indicative of attribute splitting - where data is going into one of multiple tables based on an implied attribute rather than a single table with the attribute accurately modelled as a column. (E.g. the quintessentially bad example would be to have `MaleEmployees` and `FemaleEmployees` tables rather than a single `Employees` table where `Gender` is included as column)

Comment: The actual query is not this simple, and I'm not the architect either - just looking for a more efficient way of inserting data. Thanks

Comment: Try using select...into #[temp table], @Elle

Comment: You *cannot* parametrize the table (or column) name in a standard SQL statement. If you really must have this, then you **must use** dynamic SQL - with all its warts and drawbacks....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to use dynamic SQL to do this:

```
declare @list int='51'       -- change
declare @language int='152'    -- change
DECLARE @TableX varchar(100) = 'TableX'
DECLARE @SQL varchar(500)

SET @SQL = 'insert into [DB].[Table] ([list], [value2], [language])
Select ' + CAST(@list as varchar(5)) + ' , value2, ' + CAST(@language as varchar(5)) + '
From
    [DB2].[' + @TableX + '] '

exec @SQL
```

Of course this is a simple example, I would highly recommend you parameterize it and use executeSQL instead of exec.

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't ready to change your data model, but your tables (TableA, ..., TableZ) are the same, you can use a VIEW like this:

```
CREATE VIEW MyTables
AS
    SELECT [value1], [value2], [value3], [value4], 'TableA' AS TableName
    FROM [DB2].[TableA]

    UNION ALL

    /*
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
    */

    SELECT [value1], [value2], [value3], [value4], 'TableY'
    FROM [DB2].[TableY]

    UNION ALL

    SELECT [value1], [value2], [value3], [value4], 'TableZ'
    FROM [DB2].[TableZ]
GO
```

and then use:

```
declare @list int= 51        -- change
declare @language int = 152    -- change

insert into [DB].[Table]
      ([list]
      ,[value2]
      ,[language])

Select 
      @list,
      value2,
      @language
FROM MyTables m
    JOIN [SomeTable] s ON s.[Table] = m.TableName
WHERE s.list = @list 
    AND s.language = @language
```